# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Tags: python, telebot

Кусок кода на котором ошибка

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callbacks(call):
    if call.data == "Да":
        chat_id = call.message.chat.id
        a = sql.execute("SELECT id FROM idfornotes").fetchone()
        __id = a
        sql.execute("DELETE FROM idfornotes")
        db.commit()

        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO notes VALUES ({__id}, '{note}')")
        db.commit()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Записка готова!')

        __id += 1
        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO idfornotes VALUES ({__id})")
        db.commit()
    elif call.data == 'Нет':
        chat_id = call.message.chat.id
        bot.send_message(chat_id, note)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Перепиши свою записку')
```

Создание бд

```
db = sqlite3.connect('server.db', check_same_thread=False)
sql = db.cursor()
sql.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (
idnote INT,
textnote TEXT
)""")
db.commit()
sql.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS idfornotes (
id INT
)""")
db.commit()
sql.execute("INSERT INTO idfornotes VALUES (1)")
```

Полный код

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5441826542:AAHwzPPgxhWEsRUXkhJE2uq0JiH_ZjO5jt0')

db = sqlite3.connect('server.db', check_same_thread=False)
sql = db.cursor()
sql.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (
idnote INT,
textnote TEXT
)""")
db.commit()
sql.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS idfornotes (
id INT
)""")
db.commit()
sql.execute("INSERT INTO idfornotes VALUES (1)")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    markup.row('Создать записку')
    markup.row('Смотреть записки')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствую в заметках! Этот телеграм бот создан для заметок или записок которые может посмотреть каждый!', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message(message):
    if message.text == 'Создать записку':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши свою записку')
        global write
        write = True
    elif message.text == 'Смотреть записки':
        sql.execute("SELECT id FROM notes")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, sql.fetchall())
    else:
        if write == True:
            global note
            note = message.text
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Да', callback_data='Да')
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Нет', callback_data='Нет')
            markup.add(btn1)
            markup.add(btn2)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text + '\nВсё верно?', reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неизвестная комманда!')
    print(message.text)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callbacks(call):
    if call.data == "Да":
        chat_id = call.message.chat.id
        a = sql.execute("SELECT id FROM idfornotes").fetchone()
        __id = a
        sql.execute("DELETE FROM idfornotes")
        db.commit()

        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO notes VALUES ({__id}, '{note}')")
        db.commit()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Записка готова!')

        __id += 1
        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO idfornotes VALUES ({__id})")
        db.commit()
    elif call.data == 'Нет':
        chat_id = call.message.chat.id
        bot.send_message(chat_id, note)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Перепиши свою записку')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Надо знать данные, которые вставляются, скорее всего там апостроф неэкранированный

Comment: Добавил полный код

Comment: токен можно убрать, надо знать что в переменной note находится и на какой строчке ошибка?

Comment: На 57 строке ошибка

Comment: Когда ошибка возникает, что в переменной `note` находится?

Comment: Сообщение которое отправил пользователь

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю.. Что в нём конкретно? Какой текст? Из-за этого и возникает ошибка

Comment: Например пишу Привет он выдаёт ошибку. Я тебя несовсем понимаю

Comment: `sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO notes VALUES ({__id}, {note})")` в этой строчке у тебя кавычки лишние рядом с `note`

Comment: Не помогло, кавычки убрал но ошибка такаяже

Comment: `__id = a[0]`  смотрите хотя бы что вы из бд получаете, запрос к бд возвращает кортеж, а не число либо строку

Comment: Спасибо! Сразу не заметил.